Understanding kinetic energy
Let's assume I am on a boat and I throw rocks (image courtesy from Wikipedia):

From my point of view, throwing the first rock and throwing the second rock appears to make no difference. It is the same "work" I am doing. When I release a rock, it has gained a velocity $v_r$ from my point of view.
By conservation of linear momentum (because we assume no friction and no external forces), the boat will go forward
Note that there is no energey conservation, since I am using my muscles and spending unspecified amount of joules.
Let's assume the boat+man+rocks is initially 1000 kg, and each rock is 1 kg.
When I throw rocks, the velocity is 100 m/s (yes I am strong)
Throwing first rock
Seeing the scene from an inertial frame where the velocity of everything is initially zero, by conservation of linear momentum, the velocity of the boat after first throw $v_{b_1}$ is:
$$v_{b_1} = \frac{1}{999} v_r$$
Which is $\approx 0.1 \space m/s$.
Throwing second rock
Linear momentum of the boat alone is now $v_{b_1} 999$.
We can apply conservation of linear momentum again:
$$v_{b_1} 999 = v_{b_2} 998 - (v_r + v_{b_1})$$
Thus:
$$v_{b_2} = \frac{1}{998} [v_r + v_{b_1} 1000]$$
Which is $\approx 0.2 \space m/s$.
Question

Is the reasoning correct?
Do you agree that, from my point of view (rock thrower), the two throws represent the same effort for me in term of joules?
In that case, the boat as seen from an external observer has (approximately) doubled its speed between throw 1 and throw 2, yielding 4 times more kinetic energy, why is that?


Kinetic energy is relative

This is essentially the same as the rocket equation.

"Kinetic energy is relative": the kinetic energy of the boat is not something virtual, I could retrieve it by getting it hitting a spring on the water side for example. If I get 4 times more energy with 2 rocks than with 1, where does it come from?

What the person on the ground sees as you throw the stone is you moving one way and the stone moving the other. So do you think that you are doing the same amount of work to get the stone to move a fixed speed greater than you? The stone is first moving in the same direction as you and then moves in the opposite direction.

If we were to retrieve the kinetic energy of the boat from outside, we would get 5 joules after the first throw, and 20 after the second. However, the boat is not the only object moving, there are also the rocks. The first rock energy will be 5000 joules, but the second is moving slower because it was thrown from a boat moving at 0.1m/s. It moves at 99.9m/s in the observer frame, which results in 4990 joules. Those 10 less joules are the one we find in the boat.
